# Unable to iterate through all the alarms on cloudwatch using boto3 paginate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to list all the alarms in AWS Cloudwatch. Currently I have around 200. However, when I try to list them I get maximum 100. I try paginating, but unable to go to next page or use next token.

Below is the code snippet

```
response = client.describe_alarms(StateValue='OK', MaxRecords = 100)
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(StateValue='OK',
                                        PaginationConfig={
                                        'MaxItems': 100,
                                        'PageSize': 100,

    })
for x in response_iterator:
    print(x)
```

I am getting only 100 records. When I change the max value to 200 or the actual number, it gives error saying 100 is the maximum. How to get all 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `paginator.paginate()` method, you are passing `'MaxItems': 100`. That is going to limit the total number of items returned by your paginator to 100, regardless of how many *total* items there are. If you get rid of that argument, you'll get a paginator that will paginate over all of your alarms.

You can run this snippet of code to print how many alarms each page in your paginator is returning:

```
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(StateValue='OK')
for i in response_iterator:
    print(len(i['MetricAlarms']),"alarms found")
```